# How to get the path of .py files under Azure function in Azure portal

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am working on Python Azure function. Below is the part of the code.

```
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
        df2= df1.loc[0, 'version']
        ipversion= f"testversion{df2}.py"
        start_path = 'E:\Azure\Azure_FUNC'
        path_to_file = os.path.join(start_path, ipversion)
        logging.info(f"path_to_file: {path_to_file}")
        path = Path(path_to_file)
        version= f"testversion{df2}"
        
        
if ip:
    if path.is_file():
        module = 'Azure_FUNC.' + version
        my_module = importlib.import_module(module)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"{my_module.add(ip)}")
    else:
         return func.HttpResponse(f" This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.Flex calculation = {default.mult(ip)}")
else:
         return func.HttpResponse(
         "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.,
         status_code=200
    )
```

`Azure_FUNC` is my function name.

`testversion1`, `testversion2` and `default` are 3 `.py` files under this function.

In the above code, based on the input version provided from the API call, the code checks if that version .py is available and imports the module from that particular version and executes the code. If the given version .py file is not available, it is going to execute default .py file.

This works fine in my local. But when I deploy this function to Azure, I am unable to find the path for testversion1 and testversion2 files in the Azure portal under Azure functions.
Please let me know how to get the path of these files and how to check these files based on the input version provided from the API call.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you would deploy the Azure Python Function Project to Linux Function App, then you can see the location of your trigger files (i.e., `.py` files) in the path of:

Open Kudu Site of your Function App > Click on **SSH** >

[image]