# Azure function folder is not present in the root directory

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working on the Azure functions. When I deploy the function to Azure portal, I am unable to find the function and function files in the wwwroot folder. The complete code is here [How to get the path of .py files under Azure function in Azure portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73082164/how-to-get-the-path-of-py-files-under-azure-function-in-azure-portal)
Someone please advise.

Comment: As I have seen, another thread given is posted in MSFT Q&A forum by you, could you please elaborate your current thread here - how you deployed through any IDEs or using any pipelines?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I have deployed using Azure devops  pipeline.

Comment: I see the function folder in the below path. /tmp/build/expressbuild>

Comment: Check the Kudu Site > SSH if you deployed your function app to the Linux OS - there you can see all the project files